Tiptap Editor applying marks cancels combination of korean characters when the mark is created for the first time
When I apply marks to Tiptap Editor, it cancels combination of korean characters when the mark is created for the first time.
this video demonstrates the situation. First line, which is without a mark, combines character '한' as expected. But when I apply bold mark, as soon as I type korean consonant 'ㅎ', the cursor goes to left and combination state goes away.
I am literally using the same code as tiptap doc: bold. Could you guys feed me with any possible causes?
